# How to mute Message notification sound on Filtered Messages

Tags: android, sms

I have written an application as a service which has permissions to

> READ,WRITE,RECIEVE SMS

so the class in which i extended `BroadcastReceiver` i filter the messages on basis of its content in the `onReceive` method.

Consider a scenario if i send a sms

> 'Hello sir'

the app will filter it and play a song, say the rain song

and the scenario's so on can be considered.

The concern here is the moment my song stops, The message notification tone is played.

Is there any way by which i can stop the tone from playing for only these kind of filtered messages?

Comment: how to achieve same on 4.4+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this couldn't have got much simpler...
I wasn't able to take over the Notification Sound so did a simple workaround...
Considering the messages i filter they are not messages (Commands to the application in reality with the help of which i am controlling the app) .. How about ignoring them?..

Most simple thing is dont broadcast them :)

So as soon as you have processed the command in your `onRecieve` method of `BroadcastReceiver` cancel the broadcast by calling `abortBroadcast()`